# RichHtmlField and docking toolbar

Tags: 2007, publishing-page, rich-text

The RichHtmlField (used in a MOSS publishing page layout) has a toolbar that pops up up when editing the text in the field. This toolbar can be dragged around the page, but it gets a bit annoying when there is a lot of text in the field.

Has anyone ever tried to 'dock' the toolbar to the top of the page so that it will maintain its position when editing and scrolling through large chunks of content?

Answer (score 1):

Telerik's free [RadEditor for MOSS Lite Edition](http://www.telerik.com/community/free-products.aspx) lets you dock the toolbar to the top of the page.  I'd recommend that over the built-in RichHtmlField anyway, as it's much better for cross-browser compatiblity.

Answer (score 0):

You could possibly try docking it with jQuery but to be honest, this has been 'fixed' with SharePoint 2010 with the Ribbon UI. Investing a lot of effort in changing the default behavior in 2007 is recommendable since you'd have issues when or if upgrading to 2010 in the future.